# Before BIOS starts, Evaluation Copy message displayed

Tags: motherboard, bios

I just built a new Ryzen PC using an **ASUSTeK Crosshair VI Hero** mainboard. During power-on, before BIOS posts, there is a 1-second message in the middle of the screen:

> EVALUATION COPY

Then BIOS starts and the system boots (except when it doesn't, which is another problem for another thread).

What does this mean? Is my mainboard a demo version? Will it expire someday? Should I be worried? Should I send it back to ASUS?

Comment: Why don't you ask ASUS?

Comment: I have, but support always needs a few days/weeks to answer. My last support question to ASUS didn't get a response for a full month! Also, I am hoping this question/answer might help future users.

Comment: Well I don't think anybody here will be able to answer it ...

Comment: @DavidPostill maybe somebody has been through this already

Comment: @DavidPostill I asked ASUS and they have no idea, "never seen this issue before". So they are having me try various things such as resetting BIOS, asking if I have HDDs connected, and most recently doing USB flashback to reflash BIOS (still haven't tried yet as I don't have a functioning USB stick handy).

Comment: Long shot ... and probably doesn't really apply on UEFI systems but it might be a message from the video card BIOS ROM or GOP ROM.  In the BIOS days you would often see an initialization message from NVidia, etc. before the BIOS would show anything.  Check if your video card has a hacked or unofficial firmware flashed on it.

Comment: I know this thread was inactive for a long time, however this exact message just appeared on my system. ASUS ROG Zenith extreme. Only thing I changed was to disable fast boot in the BIOS. Also NVidia GPU. Has anything new come up since this thread started? There is really NO info about this on the web.

Comment: The solution was to do a USB BIOS Flashback as described in the handbook.